# Change the first number in a column based on condition

Tags: r, gsub, substr

I have a data frame like this:

```
  id subscriberid  intName
1  1   1234567890 asdfsadf
2  2   3243245324  dfsafdf
3  3   4532453245  dasdfsd
```

A reproducible example is as follows:

```
structure(list(id = 1:3, subscriberid = c(1234567890, 3243245324, 4532453245),
    intName = c("asdfsadf", "dfsafdf", "dasdfsd")),
    row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have an array of subid and wherever the subid matches with df$subscriberid, I have to change the first digit of the subscriber id to 9.

```
subid = c(1234567890,2345345234)
```

I tried the following:

```
for (i in df$subscriberid) {
    df$subscriberid == sub(substr(df$subscriberid,0,1),9,df$subscriberid)
}
```

I have also tried with ifelse with substr and gsub, and different other combinations.  But couldn't get through.  The desired output is

```
  id subscriberid  intName
1  1   9234567890 asdfsadf   <--- only the first digit is changed.
2  2   3243245324  dfsafdf
3  3   4532453245  dasdfsd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `ifelse` and if `subscriberid` is present in `subid` then we `paste` 9 with remaining string starting from 2nd index.

```
df$subscriberid <- with(df, ifelse(subscriberid %in% subid,
                    paste0("9",substring(subscriberid,2)), subscriberid))

df
#  id subscriberid  intName
#1  1   9234567890 asdfsadf
#2  2   3243245324  dfsafdf
#3  3   4532453245  dasdfsd
```

The benefit of using `substring` is you need to only mention the start index (here 2), the default value for stop is 1000000 which covers most of the strings.

Comment: I was constantly trying with for loop with ifelse,substr and gsub / sub.  DIdn't work.  Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

We can try building a regex pattern of matching ids, then use `grepl` to find the matching rows in your data frame:

```
regex <- paste0("\\b(", paste(subid, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
df$subscriberid <- ifelse(grepl(regex, df$subscriberid),
    paste0("9", substr(df$subscriberid, 2, nchar(df$subscriberid))),
    df$subscriberid)

df
  id subscriberid  intName
1  1   9234567890 asdfsadf
2  2   3243245324  dfsafdf
3  3   4532453245  dasdfsd
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using maths, the benefit being the results are returned as numeric, and it's quicker.

#### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, subscriberid = c(1234567890, 3243245324, 4532453245),
                     intName = c("asdfsadf", "dfsafdf", "dasdfsd")),
                row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

subid <- c(1234567890,2345345234)
```

### Method

```r
idx <- df$subscriberid %in% subid
vals <- df[ idx, "subscriberid" ]
digits <- floor( log10( vals ) )

## number of digits given by `floor( log10( vals) ) + 1`, but we want the first digit

( ( vals / 10^digits ) + 9 - floor( vals / 10^digits ) ) * (10^digits)

# [1] 9234567890
```

What this is doing is finding the indices of the data.frame which match the `subid`

It's then

- working out how many digits are in those numbers using `log10`
- dividing by 10 to the power of those digits, and flooring it to get the first integer
- subtracting that integer from 9 (your target)
- adding it back to the log10'd value
- multiplying back by 10 to the power of those digits, to get the original number of digits back

### Benchmark

```r
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  ronak = { ronak( df, subid ) },
  tim = { tim( df, subid ) },
  tmfmnk = { tmfmnk( df, subid ) },
  symbolix = { symbolix( df, subid ) },
  times = 5
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr            min         lq       mean     median         uq      max neval
# ronak    186.143804 188.618750 214.151592 191.154106 196.399341 308.4420     5
# tim      442.385985 463.510154 526.814255 506.268620 541.829769 680.0767     5
# tmfmnk   236.423472 255.418334 295.652617 295.624544 329.901976 360.8948     5
# symbolix   5.510366   5.828804   8.166222   5.850937   5.942607  17.6984     5
```

And to show the results are equal

```r
res_ronak <- ronak( df, subid )
res_tim <- tim( df, subid )
res_tmfmnk <- tmfmnk( df, subid )
res_symbolix <- symbolix( df, subid )

all.equal(res_ronak, res_tim)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(res_tim, res_tmfmnk)
# [1] TRUE
res_symbolix$subscriberid <- as.character(res_symbolix$subscriberid)
all.equal(res_tmfmnk, res_symbolix)
# [1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarking data

```r
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  subscriberid = sample(1:100000000, size = 1e5)
)
subid <- sample( df$subscriberid, size = 10 )
```

#### Benchmarking functions

```r
ronak <- function(df, subid) {
  df$subscriberid <- with(df, ifelse(subscriberid %in% subid,
                  paste0("9",substring(subscriberid,2)), subscriberid))
  return(df)
}

tim <- function(df, subid) {
  regex <- paste0("\\b(", paste(subid, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
  df$subscriberid <- ifelse(grepl(regex, df$subscriberid),
                            paste0("9", substr(df$subscriberid, 2, nchar(df$subscriberid))),
                            df$subscriberid)
  return(df)
}

tmfmnk <- function(df, subid) {
  df$subscriberid <- ifelse(df$subscriberid %in% subid, 
         sub(".", "9", df$subscriberid), df$subscriberid)
  return(df)
}

symbolix <- function(df, subid) {
  idx <- df$subscriberid %in% subid
  vals <- df[ idx, "subscriberid" ]
  digits <- floor( log10( vals ) )
  df[ idx, "subscriberid" ] <- ( ( vals / 10^digits ) + 9 - floor( vals / 10^digits ) ) * (10^digits)
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different possibility is to use `sub()`:

```
df$subscriberid <- ifelse(df$subscriberid %in% subid, 
                   sub(".", "9", df$subscriberid), df$subscriberid)

  id subscriberid  intName
1  1   9234567890 asdfsadf
2  2   3243245324  dfsafdf
3  3   4532453245  dasdfsd
```

Here, if the "subscriberid" matches "subid", the first character in "subscriberid" is replaced with 9, otherwise it stays the same.

Comment: ....thank you...I was trying to resolve using ifelse itself...but missed the sub with '.'.  Quite short and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to make use of the assignment method of `substring`

```
# create a logical vector
i1 <- df1$subscriberid %in% subid

# convert the column to character class
df1$subscriberid <- as.character(df1$subscriberid)

#assign with substring<-
substring(df1$subscriberid[i1], 1, 1) <- '9'
df1
#   id subscriberid  intName
#1  1   9234567890 asdfsadf
#2  2   3243245324  dfsafdf
#3  3   4532453245  dasdfsd
```

#### Benchmarks

Including this method along with @SymbolixAU's data (other functions taken from his post)

```
akrun <- function(df, subid) {
 i1 <- df$subscriberid %in% subid
 df$subscriberid <- as.character(df$subscriberid)
 substring(df$subscriberid[i1], 1, 1) <- '9'
  }


set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
   subscriberid = sample(1:100000000, size = 1e5)
  )
subid <- sample( df$subscriberid, size = 10 )
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
   ronak = { ronak( df, subid ) },
   tim = { tim( df, subid ) },
   tmfmnk = { tmfmnk( df, subid ) },
   symbolix = { symbolix( df, subid ) }, akrun = {akrun(df, subid)}, times = 5)
#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
#    ronak 105.073716 128.279151 140.993520 138.241632 154.89092 178.48218     5  b 
#      tim 224.610660 246.959505 263.138679 264.685503 284.93632 294.50141     5   c
#   tmfmnk 119.734979 134.949406 138.735054 135.888113 142.91750 160.18527     5  b 
# symbolix   2.487283   3.238862   8.429718   3.540119  10.80669  22.07564     5 a  
#    akrun  29.530330  33.431953  41.649046  34.772512  36.91314  73.59730     5 a
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, subscriberid = c(1234567890, 3243245324, 4532453245),
intName = c("asdfsadf", "dfsafdf", "dasdfsd")),
row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```